# Why am i getting an undefined output when I try to access value returned from async method

Tags: reactjs, react-native, es6-promise, asyncstorage

I have the following method which returns an object with 3 fields inside a different file named localStorage:

```
    const getUserProfileData = async () => {
    try {
        await AsyncStorage.getItem(CONSTANTS.USER_PROFILE).then((item) => {
        let retrievedProfile = JSON.parse(item);
        return retrievedProfile;
        });
    } catch (e) {
        throw e;
    }
    };
```

here is my file profile.js:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const retrieveProfileData = async () => {
      let retProfile = await localStorage.getUserProfileData();
      console.log("check what:  ",retProfile);
    };
    retrieveProfileData();
  }, []);
```

inside the use effect, when I attempt to log out the result I get an output of:

```
check what:   undefined
```

I have read other forums on similar problems to this but I can't seem to notice where I'm going wrong?

Comment: `getUserProfileData` doesn't explicitly returns anything. You are returning `retrievedProfile` from the callback function of `.then()` but it doesn't automatically becomes the return value of the `getUserProfileData` function. Also note that you are mixing `async-await` syntax with promise-chaining

Comment: I just changed the code based on your comments but I'm getting undefined as an output

Comment: try [this code](https://pastebin.com/2E4qpaqg)

Comment: great it works! if you don't mind me asking what exact;y is wrong with the code it wrote. because as far as I can see, the only difference between your solution and mine is that you parsed the result inside the useEffect

Comment: My first comment explains what's wrong your code. `getUserProfileData` needs to returns something explicitly and parsing the result inside the `useEffect` is optional. You could do it inside `getUserProfileData` function as well but one thing i catch the error in the calling code, i.e. inside the `useEffect` hook. You are catching and re-throwing the error from inside the `getUserProfileData` function but aren't catching and handing the error in the calling code.

Comment: Great! thank you much appreicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has to do with you mixing `async` and `.then()`. Try this way:

```
const getUserProfileData = async () => {
    try {
        const result = await AsyncStorage.getItem(CONSTANTS.USER_PROFILE)
        const retrievedProfile = JSON.parse(result);
        return retrievedProfile;
    } catch (e) {
        throw e;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const getUserProfileData = async () => {
        return AsyncStorage.getItem(CONSTANTS.USER_PROFILE);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
    const retrieveProfileData = async () => {
        try {
        let retProfile = JSON.parse(await localStorage.getUserProfileData());
        console.log("check what:  ",retProfile);
        } catch (error) {
            // handle error
        }
    };
    retrieveProfileData();
    }, []);
```